# Prevent offset of multiple Windows Explorer windows

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

For Windows 8/10: I would like for Windows Explorer to always open in the same location (i.e., no horizontal offset with second and following windows).  How can this be done?

I previously used a small (and free) utility with Windows 7/XP called Pitaschio that had this functionality.

Comment: try this 3rd party tool: http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've used it for a day now and this product seems to do the trick, although it seems to be overkill for what 'should' be a relatively simple registry tweak - if you know what to tweak.  Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: there is no tweak available. The tool looks for Windows with the specific name pattern and moves it to the defined location on the screen

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This explains the 'hop' behavior I'm getting when opening Windows Explorer window #2 when my system is redlined.  Not an elegant solution, but 'good enough' given the constraints of the Windows environment...